# difference between clear and fill a rectangle with background color in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas with white background. So when I want to clear it, is there a difference between using

```
clearRect();
fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
fillRect();
```

and

```
fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
fillRect();
```

Is using any of them considered a better practice or has an effect on the outcome of `getImageData()`?

Comment: I think `clearRect` just paints a transparent black rectangle. If then you paint that rectangle, it should be useless.

Comment: No point clearing the canvas if you are going to fill it and it will make no difference to the `getImageData` method as it just reads the pixel data no matter what it is or how it was created. I personally create a small image and use `drawImage(background,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);`  as it provides a significant performance advantage, especially when you have graduated backgrounds. The image only needs to be 8 by 8 pixels.

Comment: @Blindman67 ahh okk thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't clear it first, you'll be drawing on top of what was previously there.  If you not using any transparencies, maybe this is OK.

Another difference is that clearRect() doesn't use a white background. it uses a transparent one.

Comment: ok, but when I draw on top, it doesn't have any effect on the `imageData` does it ?

Comment: Canvas only knows pixels.  When you overwrite the pixel, the old data is not saved in anyway.